# Use nextjs to obtain strapi data and prompt that the defined attributes cannot be read

Tags: next.js, strapi

Using nextjs as the front end and Stratpi as the back end, generate data normally in the Insomnia test, and then prompt an error when obtaining output on the homepage:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'url')`

page/index.js

```
import HeroBanner from "@/components/HeroBanner";
import ProductCard from "@/components/ProductCard";
import Wrapper from "@/components/Wrapper";
import { fetchDataFromApi } from "@/utils/api";

export default function Home({ products }) {
  return (
    <>
      <main>
        <HeroBanner />
        <Wrapper>
          {/* products grid start */}
          <div className="grid grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-4 gap-2 md:gap-3 lg:gap-4 my-14  md:px-0">
            {products?.data?.map((product) => (
              <ProductCard key={product?.id} data={product} />
            ))}
          </div>
          {/* products grid end */}
        </Wrapper>
      </main>
    </>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const products = await fetchDataFromApi("/api/products?populate=*");

  return {
    props: { products },
  };
}
```

components/ProductCard.js

```
import React from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import Image from "next/image";


const ProductCard = ({ data: { attributes: p, id } }) => {

  return (
    <div className="group rounded-md shadow-xl">
      <Link href={`/product/${p.slug}`}>
        <div className="transform overflow-hidden cursor-pointer">
          <Image
            className="w-full h-full object-cover group-hover:scale-110 duration-500"      
            width={640}
            height={640}
            src={p.thumbnail.data.attributes.url}
            alt={p.name}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="p-4 text-black/[0.9]">
          <h2 className="text-sm md:text-md lg:text-lg font-medium">
            {p.name}
          </h2>
         
        </div>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductCard;
```

Testing APIs on Insomnia:

http://localhost:1337/api/products?populate= *，

return the following API:
[image]

It can be obtained normally. Write the output field p.thumnail.data.attributes.url in the card, and it will prompt that the attribute cannot be read. I don't know what to do, and I can't figure out where the problem is. Please help me.

**Other attributes can be output and displayed normally, only Thumbnail cannot display images**

Comment: Your thumbnail is array so p.thumbnail.data[0].attributes.

Comment: You can use this to make your life better https://market.strapi.io/plugins/strapi-plugin-transformer

Comment: Hello my friend, I used that plugin and the properties have been raised one level. The situation is still the same. The title and slug properties can be displayed normally, but the thumbnail image still cannot be achieved. Trying to add [0] as you mentioned, it still doesn't work